# CSS can't make header image to fit view

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with header image on my website - it's size is 1920 x 410 px.

I wan't whole image to show but somehow, parts of it on all sides get cropped.

This is my CSS:

```
#banner {
    background: url('img/kontakt-header-novi.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 410px;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: If your image is cropped on **all four sides**, it means you are not using CSS3, and `background-size` requires CSS3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cover is to display it on full size... contain always shows all of the image

```css
#banner {
    background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 410px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Comment: Tried that already, now my image fits the width, but get's repeated at the bottom part of the div

Comment: so add   background-repeat: no-repeat; to it

Comment: No problem :) !

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: contain;`

-> https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Tried that already, now my image fits the width, but get's repeated at the bottom part of the div

Comment: Try adding this property : `background-repeat: no-repeat;`